# Issue In Mysql Date Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

I've a table that has a `datetime` column such like that :

```
 ---------------------
|   date_time_column  |
 ---------------------
| 2020-09-14 14:00:13 |
| 2020-05-18 14:00:13 |
| 2021-12-14 14:00:13 |
 ---------------------
```

when I made these query

```
select * from `table` 
        where TIMESTAMP('date_time_column') < '2020-12-14 10:20:04'
```

but the result is **nothing**

Comment: This is just because your client doesn't show the full resolution (some millisecond part) of the values. Hence none of them are exactly equal to the time you've requested. Try to get those between 10:20:04 and 10:20:05 instead.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned from this query?

Comment: If you use full datetime in where condition then no need to use TIMESTAMP, just use this 

select * from `table` 
        where date_time_column < '2020-12-14 10:20:04';

Comment: 'date_time_column' is a string. Perhaps you were thinking of \`date_time_column\`

Comment: Have you tried debugging your query? What does `select *, timestamp('date_time_column') from table` yield? Also, can you share the schema for your table?

Comment: @NicoHaase I Just expect some rows that covers the condition I've given

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I've made these but there no result ,
although It gives me the correct result locally but doesn't give it on the cloud server, although I have the same DB and DB engine on both

Comment: @Dojo but I need all rows before the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting *literal string* `'date_time_column'` to a timestamp, not the actual column. As this string obviously is not a valid timestamp, you get a `null` result, which filters out all rows.

```
select timestamp('date_time_column') as res
```

```
| res  |
| :--- |
| null |
```

You wanted backticks instead of single quotes, as in:

```
select * 
from `table` 
where timestamp(`date_time_column`) < '2020-12-14 10:20:04'
```

Not quoting the identifier is good enough too:

```
where timestamp(date_time_column) < '2020-12-14 10:20:04'
```

Bottom line, the timestamp conversion offers no benefit, and will slow down the query. Just do direct filtering:

```
where date_time_column < '2020-12-14 10:20:04'
```

Comment: the problem is that I've made these query before and return no raw,
when it works locally but doesn't work on server

Comment: @AbdullahAl_Nahhal: I don't know what you are saying. The answer explains the problem (the single quotes instead of backticks), and explains how to solve it. Did you try the suggested solution(s)?